# Scrapy: SeleniumMiddleWare does not yield fully rendered HtmlResponse

Tags: selenium, scrapy, render, middleware

## Setup

Using scrapy as framework, I implemented following SeleniumMiddleWare to render the url:

```
class SeleniumMiddleware(object):
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    middleware = cls()
    crawler.signals.connect(middleware.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
    crawler.signals.connect(middleware.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    return middleware

def process_request(self, request, spider):
    request.meta['driver'] = self.driver
    self.driver.get(request.url)
    #Click button
    self.driver.find_element (
        By.XPATH, '/html/body/header/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/nav/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a'
        ).click()
    body = to_bytes(self.driver.page_source)
    return HtmlResponse(self.driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)

def spider_opened(self, spider):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(
        service=Service (r'C:\Users\j.metzger\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.30.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')
        )
def spider_closed(self, spider):
    pass
    # self.driver.close()
```

## Problem

The HtmlResponse generated by `process_request` is not fully rendered when it is received by the spider:

```
def parse(self, response, **kwargs):

    open_in_browser (response)
```

Therefore, I don't have access to all html elements in the spider.

However, the url gets fully rendered in the selenium browser. I included some wait/sleep commands without any success.

Comment: Did you remember to add it to the settings?

Comment: Yes, it is included in the DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES dict